# Bash script to rename file extension

Tags: bash, rename

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ "$#" -lt 3 ]]; then
    echo "USAGE: enter the following arguments:
    1st argument = starting directory path (e.g. . for working directory)
    2nd argument = old file extension (e.g. txt)
    3rd argument = new file extension (e.g. html 
    Note:  Do not enter any . or \. for the 2nd and 3rd arguments
    "
else 
    find "$1" -name *."$2"* -exec rename 's/\."${2}"$/."${3}"/' '{}' \;
fi
```

Example input:

```
bash rename_file_extensions.sh . txt html
```

Example output:

```
Use of uninitialized value $2 in regexp compilation at (eval 6) line 1.
```

`line 1` contains the `if statement` above. Argument `$2` is `txt`. So, I am confused as to what it is referring to.

I can run the following line and it works perfectly, but I want to have it accept bash arguments:

```
find . -name "*.txt.html*" -exec rename 's/\.txt.html.html.html$/.html/' '{}' \;
```

In this case, as you can see, there were a lot of incorrect file extensions. This line corrected all of them.

I tried editing the `find` line to:

```
find "${1}" -name '*."$2"*' -exec rename 's/\."${2}"$/."${3}"/' '{}' \;
```

This allowed me to move forward without an error; however, there was no output, and it did not change any `txt` extensions to `html` when I ran the following command, `bash rename_file_extensions.sh . txt html`.

Please help!

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to get arguments interpreted by the shell, drop the single quotes:

try

```
find "$1" -name "*.$2*" -exec rename "s/\.${2}\$/.${3}/" '{}' \;
```

or (if you want to keep quotes)

```
find "$1" -name "*.$2*" -exec rename 's/\.'"${2}"'$/.'"${3}"'/' '{}' \;
```

(and I would enclose the full argument of `-name` in double quotes or bash could expand the argument directly if some files match in the current directory)

Comment: I used `find "$1" -name "*.$2*" -exec rename 's/\.'"${2}"'$/.'"${3}"'/' '{}' \;` and it worked great! Thank you!